# How do I install Vuze?

Tags: software-installation, thirdpartyapps

I cannot figure out how to install Vuze (or Miro) on eOS.  I am unable to add the repository...

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which repository you want to add? You might want to try http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/08/install-vuze-bittorrent-client-5-7-3-in-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: It won't allow adding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'

wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt update

sudo apt install vuze

sudo apt remove vuze && sudo apt autoremove

Comment: That worked.   But we really have to go through these steps to install software on eOS?  There is no easier way?  This is going to kill eOS.  Stupid.

Comment: eOS is advertised as a Windows / OS/X replacement... with no way easy way to install software that will never happen.

Comment: Anyone know how to install Miro?

Comment: Mike, if you search for "miro linux", you'll typically find directions: http://www.getmiro.com/download/for-ubuntu/ Eventually most common apps will be available in the elementary AppCenter so you won't need the commands

Comment: I tried those instructions and I get the following error:

Comment: sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found